# how can I install mysql without errors?

Tags: mysql, installation, dpkg

This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.40, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

what should I do here ??

i tried these cmds and still the error appears:

sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. This helped me:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql*
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/ 
Then I reinstalled it:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server


sudo service mysql start
sudo mysql -u root -p
secret


sudo mysql -u root -p
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```